# Mysql multiple select query to show total result by month

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use select query for every month 1 to 12 like this. I searched from internet sub query format was little like this but it is not correct format according to my query. When I run this query for single month it is showing correct result. i want to show result in html table like this
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/feb9a/1)

[Html table Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSKc1.png)

```
SELECT 
(SELECT SUM(`current_sales`) FROM `orders` WHERE YEAR(order_date) ='2017' AND MONTH(order_date) ='10' GROUP BY  pro_id) AS October,
(SELECT SUM(`current_sales`) FROM `orders` WHERE YEAR(order_date) ='2017' AND MONTH(order_date) ='11' GROUP BY  pro_id) AS November,
(SELECT SUM(`current_sales`) FROM `orders`WHERE YEAR(order_date) ='2017' AND MONTH(order_date) ='12' GROUP BY  pro_id)  AS December
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data.

Comment: This SQLFiddle-> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/feb9a/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right path. But as you want to get `sum()` of `current_sales` for each month, you shouldn't use `Group by` in your subqueries as it will return multiple rows. Instead just put `where` condition to fetch rows for same `pro_id` as query is currently executing using `Group by` clause.

Following query will work:

```
select tmp.pro_id,
       tmp.product_name,
       tmp.nsp,       
       tmp.Jan,
       tmp.Feb,
       tmp.Mar,
       tmp.Apr,
       (tmp.Jan+tmp.Feb+tmp.Mar+tmp.Apr) as Q1,
       tmp.May,
       tmp.Jun,
       tmp.Jul,
       tmp.Aug,
       (tmp.May+tmp.Jun+tmp.Jul+tmp.Aug) as Q2,
       tmp.Sep,
       tmp.Oct,
       tmp.Nov,
       tmp.`Dec`,
       (tmp.Sep+tmp.Oct+tmp.Nov+tmp.`Dec`) as Q3
From       
( 
SELECT o.pro_id,
       p.product_name,
       p.nsp,
(case when coalesce(sum(month(order_date) = 1),0) <> 0
      then
          (SELECT SUM(`current_sales`) FROM `orders` WHERE pro_id = o.pro_id and YEAR(order_date) ='2017' AND MONTH(order_date) ='1')
 else 0
 end
 ) as Jan,
 (case when coalesce(sum(month(order_date) = 2),0) <> 0
      then
          (SELECT SUM(`current_sales`) FROM `orders` WHERE pro_id = o.pro_id and YEAR(order_date) ='2017' AND MONTH(order_date) ='2')
 else 0
 end
 ) as Feb,
(case when coalesce(sum(month(order_date) = 3),0) <> 0
      then
          (SELECT SUM(`current_sales`) FROM `orders` WHERE pro_id = o.pro_id and YEAR(order_date) ='2017' AND MONTH(order_date) ='3')
 else 0
 end
 ) as Mar,
 (case when coalesce(sum(month(order_date) = 4),0) <> 0
      then
          (SELECT SUM(`current_sales`) FROM `orders` WHERE pro_id = o.pro_id and YEAR(order_date) ='2017' AND MONTH(order_date) ='4')
 else 0
 end
 ) as Apr,
 (case when coalesce(sum(month(order_date) = 5),0) <> 0
      then
          (SELECT SUM(`current_sales`) FROM `orders` WHERE pro_id = o.pro_id and YEAR(order_date) ='2017' AND MONTH(order_date) ='5')
 else 0
 end
 ) as May,
 (case when coalesce(sum(month(order_date) = 6),0) <> 0
      then
          (SELECT SUM(`current_sales`) FROM `orders` WHERE pro_id = o.pro_id and YEAR(order_date) ='2017' AND MONTH(order_date) ='6')
 else 0
 end
 ) as Jun,
 (case when coalesce(sum(month(order_date) = 7),0) <> 0
      then
          (SELECT SUM(`current_sales`) FROM `orders` WHERE pro_id = o.pro_id and YEAR(order_date) ='2017' AND MONTH(order_date) ='7')
 else 0
 end
 ) as Jul,
(case when coalesce(sum(month(order_date) = 8),0) <> 0
      then
          (SELECT SUM(`current_sales`) FROM `orders` WHERE pro_id = o.pro_id and YEAR(order_date) ='2017' AND MONTH(order_date) ='8')
 else 0
 end
 ) as Aug,
(case when coalesce(sum(month(order_date) = 9),0) <> 0
      then
          (SELECT SUM(`current_sales`) FROM `orders` WHERE pro_id = o.pro_id and YEAR(order_date) ='2017' AND MONTH(order_date) ='9')
 else 0
 end
 ) as Sep,
(case when coalesce(sum(month(order_date) = 10),0) <> 0
      then
          (SELECT SUM(`current_sales`) FROM `orders` WHERE pro_id = o.pro_id and YEAR(order_date) ='2017' AND MONTH(order_date) ='10')
 else 0
 end
 ) as Oct,
 (case when coalesce(sum(month(order_date) = 11),0) <> 0
      then
          (SELECT SUM(`current_sales`) FROM `orders` WHERE pro_id = o.pro_id and YEAR(order_date) ='2017' AND MONTH(order_date) ='11')
 else 0
 end
 ) as Nov,
(case when coalesce(sum(month(order_date) = 12),0) <> 0
      then
          (SELECT SUM(`current_sales`) FROM `orders` WHERE pro_id = o.pro_id and YEAR(order_date) ='2017' AND MONTH(order_date) ='12')
 else 0
 end
 ) as `Dec`
from products p
inner join orders o
on p.pro_id = o.pro_id
group by o.pro_id
)tmp
group by tmp.pro_id
;
```

[Click here for DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e30f0d/15/0)

Although, I have another approach for your task which has huge query with many in-built functions of Mysql like `Group_concat()`, `Substring_Index()` etc.

Have a look at another approach:

```
select tmp2.pro_id,
       tmp2.product_name,
       tmp2.nsp,
       tmp2.Jan,
       tmp2.Feb,
       tmp2.Mar,
       tmp2.Apr,
       (tmp2.Jan+tmp2.Feb+tmp2.Mar+tmp2.Apr) as Q1,
       tmp2.May,
       tmp2.Jun,
       tmp2.Jul,
       tmp2.Aug,
       (tmp2.May+tmp2.Jun+tmp2.Jul+tmp2.Aug) as Q2,
       tmp2.Sep,
       tmp2.Oct,
       tmp2.Nov,
       tmp2.`Dec`,
       (tmp2.Sep+tmp2.Oct+tmp2.Nov+tmp2.`Dec`) as Q3
from
(
select tmp.pro_id,
       tmp.product_name,
       tmp.nsp,            
(case when coalesce(sum(tmp.month=1),0) <> 0 
      then
        substring_index
        (
           substring_index
            (
             Group_concat(tmp.total order by tmp.month separator ','),
             ',',             
               (find_in_set
                    (1,
                     Group_concat(tmp.month order by tmp.month separator ',')
                    )
               )
             ), 
            ',',
          -1                
        )
     else 0
end
) as Jan,
(case when coalesce(sum(tmp.month=2),0) <> 0 
      then
        substring_index
        (
           substring_index
            (
             Group_concat(tmp.total order by tmp.month separator ','),
             ',',             
               (find_in_set
                    (2,
                     Group_concat(tmp.month order by tmp.month separator ',')
                    )
               )
             ), 
            ',',
          -1                
        )
     else 0
end
) as Feb,
(case when coalesce(sum(tmp.month=3),0) <> 0 
      then
        substring_index
        (
           substring_index
            (
             Group_concat(tmp.total order by tmp.month separator ','),
             ',',             
               (find_in_set
                    (3,
                     Group_concat(tmp.month order by tmp.month separator ',')
                    )
               )
             ), 
            ',',
          -1                
        )
     else 0
end
) as Mar,
(case when coalesce(sum(tmp.month=4),0) <> 0 
      then
        substring_index
        (
           substring_index
            (
             Group_concat(tmp.total order by tmp.month separator ','),
             ',',             
               (find_in_set
                    (4,
                     Group_concat(tmp.month order by tmp.month separator ',')
                    )
               )
             ), 
            ',',
          -1                
        )
     else 0
end
) as Apr,
(case when coalesce(sum(tmp.month=5),0) <> 0 
      then
        substring_index
        (
           substring_index
            (
             Group_concat(tmp.total order by tmp.month separator ','),
             ',',             
               (find_in_set
                    (5,
                     Group_concat(tmp.month order by tmp.month separator ',')
                    )
               )
             ), 
            ',',
          -1                
        )
     else 0
end
) as May,
(case when coalesce(sum(tmp.month=6),0) <> 0 
      then
        substring_index
        (
           substring_index
            (
             Group_concat(tmp.total order by tmp.month separator ','),
             ',',             
               (find_in_set
                    (6,
                     Group_concat(tmp.month order by tmp.month separator ',')
                    )
               )
             ), 
            ',',
          -1                
        )
     else 0
end
) as Jun,
(case when coalesce(sum(tmp.month=7),0) <> 0 
      then
        substring_index
        (
           substring_index
            (
             Group_concat(tmp.total order by tmp.month separator ','),
             ',',             
               (find_in_set
                    (7,
                     Group_concat(tmp.month order by tmp.month separator ',')
                    )
               )
             ), 
            ',',
          -1                
        )
     else 0
end
) as Jul,
(case when coalesce(sum(tmp.month=8),0) <> 0 
      then
        substring_index
        (
           substring_index
            (
             Group_concat(tmp.total order by tmp.month separator ','),
             ',',             
               (find_in_set
                    (8,
                     Group_concat(tmp.month order by tmp.month separator ',')
                    )
               )
             ), 
            ',',
          -1                
        )
     else 0
end
) as Aug,
(case when coalesce(sum(tmp.month=9),0) <> 0 
      then
        substring_index
        (
           substring_index
            (
             Group_concat(tmp.total order by tmp.month separator ','),
             ',',             
               (find_in_set
                    (9,
                     Group_concat(tmp.month order by tmp.month separator ',')
                 )
               )
             ), 
            ',',
          -1                
        )
     else 0
end
) as Sep,
(case when coalesce(sum(tmp.month=10),0) <> 0 
      then
        substring_index
        (
           substring_index
            (
             Group_concat(tmp.total order by tmp.month separator ','),
             ',',             
               (find_in_set
                    (10,
                     Group_concat(tmp.month order by tmp.month separator ',')
                    )
               )
             ), 
            ',',
          -1                
        )
     else 0
end
) as Oct,                      
(case when coalesce(sum(tmp.month=11),0) <> 0 
      then
        substring_index
        (
           substring_index
            (
             Group_concat(tmp.total order by tmp.month separator ','),
             ',',             
               (find_in_set
                    (11,
                     Group_concat(tmp.month order by tmp.month separator ',')
                    )
               )
             ), 
            ',',
          -1                
        )
     else 0
end
) as Nov,
(case when coalesce(sum(tmp.month=12),0) <> 0 
      then
        substring_index
        (
           substring_index
            (
             Group_concat(tmp.total order by tmp.month separator ','),
             ',',             
               (find_in_set
                    (12,
                     Group_concat(tmp.month order by tmp.month separator ',')
                    )
               )
             ), 
            ',',
          -1                
        )
     else 0
end
) as `Dec`
from       
(
select o.pro_id,
       p.product_name,
       p.nsp,
       sum(o.current_sales) as total,
       month(order_date) as month
from
products p
inner join orders o
on p.pro_id = o.pro_id
group by o.pro_id,month(order_date)
)tmp
group by tmp.pro_id
)tmp2
group by tmp2.pro_id
;
```

[Click here for Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e30f0d/6/0)

Now, you can run both the queries against your actual data and select one with less execution time.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Kindly verify both approaches and check both demos as well. Feel free to ask any doubts.

Comment: Thanks alot @Harshil Doshi. You are awesome.

Comment: i applied this query it is working fine but i want to add a WHERE clause WHERE d_id = 4, so it should show this only that result but when i apply it shows the same result for every d_id. what should i do? Thanks again

Comment: Where did you add the `where` clause?

Comment: After this "on p.pro_id = o.pro_id" and before Group by

Comment: i m using this is it fine to use? "WHERE ? IN (o.d_id, 0)"

Comment: if i provide any d_id otherwise it will show the result like it is showing right now. Am i doing correct?

Comment: If you add where d_id = 4 then you'll get the same result as you're currently getting. Coz in your sqlfiddle you only have one value for d_id and that is 4.

Comment: Yes u r right i used only 1 dummy record but but i am using where clause as i mentioned before will it work fine?